# Storing Calculated fields in database - Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I have the following tables in my laravel project

```
users
profiles
fitness_reports
```

Each profile belongs to a user and each fitness report belongs to a profile. A user can have one profile and multiple fitness reports connected via a profile id. This is to show weekly reports to the users.

Profiles table has columns like user_id, dob, age, height, weight, waist, hip, neck, exercise_level which are entered by the user and are stored properly in the profiles table. This works fine.

fitness_reports table has columns like profile_id, 'bmi', 'bmr', 'bai', 'weight_status', 'fat_us', 'fat_bmi', 'fat_mass', 'lean_mass', 'fat_category'. All these fields are calculated fields which needs to be calculated automatically whenever there is a update in the profiles table.

Previously i had a single model with calculated fields which worked fine with below

```php
public function getBmiAttribute() {
    return ($this->weight / ($this->height * $this->height));
}
```

and then saving it in the same profile model with controller code

```php
public function store(Request $request)
  {
      $profile = new Profile();
      $profile->weight = $request->get('weight');
      $profile->height = $request->get('height');
      $profile->dob = $request->get('dob');
      $profile->age;
      $profile->bmi;
      $profile->save();
      return back()->with('success', 'Your profile has been updated.');
  }
```

But now as we have created a separate fitness_reports table to track weekly reports. How to do the same with this scenario.

I have tried to this

```php
use App\Models\Profile;

class FitnessReport extends Model
{
  .....

  public function getBmiAttribute($value)
   {
    return ($this->weight / ($this->height * $this->height));
   }
}
```

But this doesnt work. Nothing gets saved. How to save a different report whenever user updated his current info in profile.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Are you using a MySQL database?

Comment: yes im using mysql

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    // since this is really a function of the profile data
    public function getBmiAttribute()
    {
        return ($this->weight / ($this->height * $this->height));
    }
}
```

Then when you store the FitnessReport:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $profile = Auth::user()->profile;
    $report = new FitnessReport();
    $report->bmi = $profile->bmi;
    $report->save();
    return back()->with('success', 'Fitness report saved.');
}
```

... or something similar from wherever you need to save the report.

Comment: I want to save the bmi field in the fitness_reports table. How to do that? I have separate controllers for profile and fitness_results. So just using like use App\Models\Profile would give me access to bmi value in the controller?

Comment: @SrikanthGopi I've update the answer with an option for calculating the bmi etc in the profile model and then saving the result in the fitness report as needed, either in a controller or an event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new `Fitness Report` every time `Profile` is Updated
So you can use the `event handlers` of `Eloquent Models`.

set an event handler to `Prfile Model` `updated` event to save a new `Fitness Report`.

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

        parent::updated(function ($profile) {

            FitnessReport::create([
                'profile_id' => $profile->id,
                'bmi' => $profile->weight / ( $profile->height * $profile->height ),
                ...
                ... // other necessary fields
            ]);

        });
    }

    // relationship to fitness reports.
    public function fitnessReports()
    {
        return this->hasMany(FitnessReport::class);
    }
}
```

this happens all the time you create a new model. and `bmi` will be automatically set to the model and saved.

try to do the same thing with `updating event`